# how to do selective join in pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have two datasets..
main_data.txt

```
{"id":"foo", "some_field:12354, "score":0}
{"id":"foobar", "some_field:12354, "score":0}
```

score_data.txt

```
{"id":"foo", "score":1}
{"id":"foobar","score":20}
```

....

So in main_data.. score is initialized to 0..
Also.. main_data and score_data have some ids in common..

For the ids which are common:
I want to replace "score" in main_data with score in score_data

And if the element is absent.. then I want to let the score to 0 itself..

Comment: First of all, you need to have the data loaded into a Pig data structure.  What does your `LOAD` statement look like?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have "score" initialized to 0? You could simply skip that, join `main_data` (LEFT OUTER) and `score_data`. Regardless if you skip or not, this should work:

```
main_data = LOAD USING SOME STORAGE; -- asume we have id as column
score_data = LOAD USING SOME STORAGE; -- asume we have id, score as columns
joined_data = JOIN main_data BY main_data::id LEFT OUTER, score_data BY score_data::id;
results = FOREACH joined_data GENERATE main_data::id, (score_data::score IS NULL ? 0 : score_data::score);
STORE results USING SOMETHING SOMEWHERE;
```